# Suppress all windows XP dialog boxes

Tags: windows-xp, gui

I have a Windows XP box (Pro... I think) that is used for **NOTHING** more then a photo frame. The great part it attached to a large screen. ;)

Since it's a photo frame there is no keyboard or mouse. Everynow and then I get a dialog box that pops up requiring me to attach one or the other to click OK.

The current nemesis is the Window virtual memory.

So how can I suppress every dialog box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to interpret "The current nemesis is the Window virtual memory" as the warning you receive as a popup bubble. If you want to disable bubbles, follow [this](http://www.winbookcorp.com/_technote/WBTA20000902.htm).

Note that if you are getting prompts about virtual memory being too low you probably have a memory leak somewhere.

Comment: Agreed: It wouldn't hurt to boot the photo frame from time to time.

Comment: Yeah a memory leak wouldn't surprise me. There is some paperclips and bubble gum software on that box to pull photos from flickr.

Comment: @harrymc - I might do all three....
1 - Disable notifications.

2 - Schedule a nightly reboot.

3 - Wright my own Flickr software.